# Both Shapiro-Wilk normality test results are non-parametric

Tags: normality-assumption, sas

I have 2 resuls from normality testing via Shapiro-Wilk test:

[image] and [image].

If I understand correctly, both have *p* > α = 0,05 which indicates that both have normal distribution. So for my next analysis, am I allowed to use paired t-test (i.e. Wilcoxon)?

All other charts shows that it is **definitely** non-parametrical distribution:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What to do now? Go by the calculation or just simply **reject** by taking a look on charts?

Thank you.

-- IM NEW TO STATISTICS, SORRY FOR ANY INCONVENIENCE --

Comment: You over-interpret your histograms: as the tests indicate, these data are consistent with a hypothesis that they were randomly and independently generated by a common Normal distribution.  BTW, the opposite of "Normal" is not "nonparametric:" it's "non-Normal."  Those are two distinct things.

Comment: Alright, I am sorry for that mistake. So the conclusion is that this is normal distribution? Even though the second Q-Q plot's values ale completely out of line?

Comment: They are not out of line in the second plot.  It appears only that your software has drawn an irrelevant line.  If *you* had to draw a line through the points, where would you put it?

Comment: That line is drawn according to results of my *mean* and *std. deviation*, btw Im using SAS 9.4

Comment: That doesn't look directly relevant to your question.  You ask whether--separately--each of two groups of data is consistent with a Normal distribution.  Using some estimate developed from *both groups together* won't answer such a question.

Comment: Well you think it is normal distribution, I think it is not.. what now? Should I do Wilcoxon signed test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135481/discussion-between-martin-dub-and-whuber).

Comment: Some wrong use of terminology here. (1) Not rejecting normality doesn't mean data are normal (generally not rejecting a null hypothesis doesn't mean the null hypothesis is true. (2) There is no such thing as a "non-parametric distribution". You seem to mean "non-normal". (3) I don't understand what you mean by "both results are non-parametric". "non-parametric" isn't an adjective that can apply to test results. (4) Quite generally such tests cannot decide whether you are "allowed" to use a paired t-test. (5) I don't get why you write "paired t-test (i.e. Wilcoxon)". These are not the same.

Comment: You seem to have very small sample sizes. One issue with small sample sizes is that it is hardly possible to tell apart normal from non-normal distributions. The distribution can look quite non-normal but still be compatible with normality, because there can be much random variation in (normal or non-normal) small samples.